# choose only related columns ignoring rest

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have one question paper when i start the test  then i got next question according to id but topic ids are randomly means my topic ids are alternately. suppose my topic id is 4 and primary keys are alternatively for this when i click for next question then i got blank if topic id is not 4 please help me

here is my code

```
    private void getQuestion(int no)
    {
    //con.Open();
    //    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(TopicId) from QuetionBank where TopicId='"+topicID+"'", con);
    //   Int32 count1 = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    //  lbltotQue.Text = count1.ToString();
    //  con.Close();

        topicID=((Practice_Test)frm1).cmbTopic.SelectedValue.ToString();

       // clear();
        if (incQuestion <= 40)//&& topicID!= null
        {

            string str = "select * from QuetionBank  where TopicID='" + topicID + "' and QuetionId='" + no + "' ";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(str, con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "QuetionBank");
            //    da.Fill(ds, "Answer");

            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataRow dtr;
                int i = 0;
                while (i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
                {
                    dtr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i];
                    //   Session["Answer"] = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(dtr["Correct"].ToString()) - 1);
               LblQuestionNo.Text =+ incQuestion + " " +"/100".ToString();
               lblQuestionId.Text = dtr["QuetionId"].ToString();
               RtfDirection.Text = dtr["Direction"].ToString();
               rtfQuestion.Text = dtr["Question"].ToString();
               rbOptionA.Text=(dtr["OptionA"].ToString());
               rbOptionB.Text=(dtr["OptionB"].ToString());
               rbOptionC.Text = (dtr["OptionC"].ToString());
               rbOptionD.Text = (dtr["OptionD"].ToString());
               rtbOptionE.Text = (dtr["OptionE"].ToString());
               rtbSolution.Text = (dtr["Solution"].ToString());
                    //pbDirection.ImageLocation= dtr["Image_Direction"].ToString();
                    //pbQuestion.ImageLocation = dtr["Image_Quetion"].ToString();
                    //pbOptionA.ImageLocation = dtr["Image_OptionA"].ToString();
                    //pbOptionB.ImageLocation = dtr["Image_OptionB"].ToString();
                    //pbOptionC.ImageLocation = dtr["Image_OptionC"].ToString();
                    //pbOptionD.ImageLocation = dtr["Image_OptionD"].ToString();
                    //pbOptionE.ImageLocation = dtr["Image_OptionE"].ToString();
                    //pbSolution.ImageLocation = dtr["Image_Solution"].ToString();
               lblCorrect.Text = dtr["CorrectAns"].ToString();
                    i++;


                }
            incQuestion += 1;
            }





        }



           // }

        //}
```

Comment: what is the "incQuestion" variable ??

Comment: Apart from the feact you query is open for SQL-injection can you please rewrite the question? It´s really hard to understand what you mwan (punctuation and formattings are really hellful sometimes).